# Bad Padding Exception JPA AttributeConverter / MultiThreading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, aes, eclipselink

I have sensitive data which needs to be encrypted when saving in the database so that no one can read it even if they look into the database. So the approach I  followed is to use `AttributeConverter`.

I created a class like this

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class SensitiveDataConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private final EncryptDecryptUtils encryptDecryptUtils;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new vulnerable data converter.
     * Not using {@link javax.inject.Inject}  because @Inject doesn't
     * work with AttributeConverter
     *
     */
    public SensitiveDataConverter() {
        this.encryptDecryptUtils = EncryptDecryptUtils.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        return attribute != null ?  encryptDecryptUtils.encrypt(attribute): null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData != null ?  encryptDecryptUtils.decrypt(dbData): null;
    }
```

And In my Entity class I have sensitive fields marked as

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = SensitiveDataConverter.class)
private String sensitiveData;
```

There are more than one column with such sensitive data.

My Encrypt/Decrypt code looks like this. I am using 128 length Key.

```
private static final byte[] IV = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
private static final IvParameterSpec IV_PARAMETER_SPEC = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 128;

private final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
private final Cipher cipher;

private static volatile EncryptDecryptUtils instance;

private String secretKey = "someSecretkey";

private String salt = "someSalt";

private EncryptDecryptUtils() {

    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                65536, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while encrypting: {}", e);
        throw new EncryptDecryptException("Error while initializing encryption mechanism", e);
    }

}

public static EncryptDecryptUtils getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (EncryptDecryptUtils .class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new EncryptDecryptUtils();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt){
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, IV_PARAMETER_SPEC);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    } catch (BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while encrypting: {}", stringToEncrypt, e);
        throw new EncryptDecryptException("Error while encrypting sensitive data", e);
    }
}

public  String decrypt(String stringToDecrypt){
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, IV_PARAMETER_SPEC);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringToDecrypt)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while decrypting: {}", stringToDecrypt, e);
        throw new EncryptDecryptException("Error while decrypting sensitive data", e);
    }
}
```

The whole code flow works perfectly fine. But every now and then while decrypting I see this exception being thrown

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Invalid PKCS#5 padding length: <somenumber>
    at iaik.security.cipher.f.b(Unknown Source)
    at iaik.security.cipher.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at iaik.security.cipher.a.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at com.bmw.scmaer.scenario.util.EncryptDecryptUtils.decrypt(EncryptDecryptUtils.java:xxx)
```

If I rerun the same flow again. It works. It is occuring intermittently. So I am not able to find out the root cause of this.

I am using JPA and eclipselink as ORM.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: may be that some 'stringToDecrypt' are truncated, BadPaddingException occurs when key, vector or text to decrypt are corrupt

Comment: @imperezivan, that is not true. two reasons. 1. If you look at the code, I am logging, the stringToDecrypt whenever there is an exception. And I see complete stringToDecrypt there.2 If it is truncated, how would it work, if i rerun

Comment: Presumably, this is rather a multithreading than an encryption/decryption issue. That's also supported by the sporadic occurrence of the problem. There seems to be no synchronization for the encryption and decryption process which means that both processes are not performed atomically. Btw a comment on the IV: It seems as if the IV is a zero-sequence for all messages. However, for each message a different and random IV needs to be used (of course, that's not the reason for your problem, but a security issue).

Comment: @Topaco My guess is the same. It could be a multithreading issue. Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle this, without compromising(much) on the performance

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a multithreading-expert. My two suggestions, both not very sophisticated, are both likely to significantly reduce the performance. One solution could be to use a local `cipher`-instance in both, the `encrypt`- and `decrypt`-method. Then, no synchronization should be necessary. The second solution could be to declare both, the `encrypt`- and `decrypt`- method `synchronized` or to use a `synchronized`-block in both methods. I suspect that the second solution is more performant because the creation of the `cipher`-instance is probably expensive.